# How to search for a specific value with multiples values inside a cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet in Excel that kinda looks like this:

| SubjectID | ValidQuestions | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XXX000 | 10 | Python |
| CCC111 / TTT222 | 9 | Data Structure |

.
.
The first column represents the ID code that identifies a certain subject. The second one is the number of valid questions that can be used in a exam. The third one is the name of the subject.

I have another tab that kind looks like this:

| SubjectID | ValidQuestions |
| --- | --- |
| XXX000 |  |
| CCC111 |  |

But this time, the SubjectId column contains only one value that is not separated by a slash and the ValidQuestions column is empty. I need to fill the second one with values from the first tab. I tried to use VLOOKUP but it's not working. I would appreciate help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Microsoft-365, then I would recommend to use `XLOOKUP()`.

```
=XLOOKUP("*"&B9&"*",$A$2:$A$3,$B$2:$B$3,,2)
```

To make it dynamic spill array use `XLOOKUP()` with `BYROW()` function.

```
=BYROW(B9:B10,LAMBDA(x,XLOOKUP("*"&x&"*",$A$2:$A$3,$B$2:$B$3,,2)))
```

`MAP()` could be another alternate. Use-

```
=MAP(B9:B10,LAMBDA(x,XLOOKUP("*"&x&"*",A2:A3,B2:B3,,2)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `VLOOKUP()` with **[wildcard character * (asterisk)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-wildcard-characters-in-searches-ef94362e-9999-4350-ad74-4d2371110adb)**

[image]

• Formula used in cell `F2`

```
=VLOOKUP(E2&"*",$A$2:$C$3,2,0)
```

---

You can also use `INDEX()` & `MATCH()` with `ISNUMBER()` & `SEARCH()`

[image]

• Formula used in cell `F2`

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$3,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E2,$A$2:$A$3)),0))
```

---